# Как всегда держать открытым браузер с использованием Selenium WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Имеется скрипт, который с помощью `selenium` заходит на сайт, делает скрин страницы и закрывает вкладку. 
Это немного неудобно, т.к на каждый запрос приходится открывать/закрывать браузер, на это уходит около 10~ секунд.
Поэтому решил сделать следующее:

- Открыть браузер только один раз и сделать его активным для всех последующих запросов
- Для каждого запроса делать новую вкладку

Проблема в том, что исходя из моего кода

```
def get_screen(coin):
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, executable_path='/home/schedude/webdriver/geckodriver')
    driver.get('https://google.com')
    sleep(1.5)
    print('I find site')
    driver.quit()
```

При каждом вызове функции открывается новое окно программы.

Подскажите, в какой способ я могу преобразовать код, чтоб при запуске он уже обращался к открытому браузеру и просто делал новую вкладку.

Такое вообще возможно?

К слову, эта часть скрипта импортируется в  мое Django приложение, возможно это даст некие доп. возможности.

Подскажите, в каком направлении двигаться

Answer (score 2):

Нужно взять и проинициализировать браузер вне функции:)
Вот так, к примеру:

```
def get_screen(driver, coin):
     driver.get('https://google.com')
     sleep(1.5)
     print('I find site')

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
web_driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, executable_path='/home/schedude/webdriver/geckodriver')
# Много вызовов функции get_screen
web_driver.quit()  # конец программы
```

Ещё можно написать класс, чтобы не передавать объект драйвера каждый раз, или использовать глобальную переменную (что не очень хорошо). Я лично использовал вариант из своего примера. В Django возможно придётся прибегнуть к использованию глобальных переменных, но не думаю, что это сильно осложнит задачу

Answer (score 0):

Я когда-то делал задание, где надо было отослать письмо в Mail.ru и потом открыть вкладку для Yandex.ru и там тоже отослать письмо. Новую вкладку открывал и переключался на нее так:

```
# Open a new tab with mail.yandex.ru
newtab = driver.execute_script("window.open('https://mail.yandex.ru/','_blank');")

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda d: len(d.window_handles) == 2)

# switch windows
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])

# wait to make sure the new window is loaded
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda d: d.title != "")

#driver.switch_to.window
WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
```

Предлагаю поразмышлять в эту сторону.